# Dynamics CRM Customization SiteMap in Interactive Service Hub Mode

Tags: dynamics-crm, interactive-service-hub

Dynamics SiteMap can customize permission by using 
Area/Group/SubArea/Privilege
to show different SiteMap content for different logon user.
But it doesn't work in interactive service hub mode.
How can I fix it?

Comment: CRM version ? Also, what's been done, what happens, what is expected to happen ?

Comment: CRM version is 8.2.2.112, On-Promises. Normally, I expect when user1 logon, user1 can only see Desktop, when user2 logon, user2 can see Desktop,Sales and Service. It work very well by using privilege under subarea but it won't work in interactive service hub mode. This is how privilege control in sitemap, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309286.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Interactive Service Hub, now being called as [Customer Service Hub app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/customer-service/customer-service-hub-user-guide-basics#understand-the-sitemap-navigation) is available only for minimal security roles & with minimal entities (related to service module). It’s mainly designed for managing knowledge articles and case management.

> These options are available only to users with the Customer Service app access role , System Administrator role, or System Customizer role.
>
> The Customer Service Hub comes with an enhanced sitemap to enable easy navigation of the interface
>
> Any record types that are enabled for mobile are also available for use in the Customer Service Hub. However, these records are read-only.
>
> The navigation bar for the Customer Service Hub is different from the navigation bar in the Dynamics 365 web application.

Dynamics CRM is evolving with App concept (latest version), where you can have dedicated App with url, clubbing needed entities, dedicated sitemap, controlled by security roles, etc.

[This way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48431470/7920473) you can have different app for different roles which means set of users, without overloaded navigation items, jewels & icons.